# Insert rows in the correct order, if they do not already exist in the current position

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rbind

I have two data frames (**df1** and **df2**) and I want to insert all consecutive rows in the correct order from df2 to df1, if they do not already exist in the current position. Column **Index** decides whether to insert or not, but this column is not unique, so it may appear multiple times in df1 or df2. I have some code, but it's extremely slow for much bigger dataframes, so I'd like to ask if there's a way to do it more efficiently. If you run my code, you'll see the expected result.
Thanks in advance for your help.

**df1 looks like:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(datetime=c("2016-03-02 16:44:32 UTC","2016-03-02 16:51:32 UTC","2016-03-02 16:53:45 UTC","2016-03-02 19:12:15 UTC",
                           "2016-03-02 19:12:32 UTC","2016-03-02 19:12:36 UTC","2016-03-02 19:13:50 UTC","2016-03-03 05:44:54 UTC",
                           "2016-03-03 05:45:06 UTC","2016-03-03 05:45:11 UTC","2016-03-03 05:45:27 UTC","2016-03-03 05:45:42 UTC",
                           "2016-03-03 05:45:52 UTC","2016-03-03 05:45:57 UTC","2016-03-03 05:46:12 UTC","2016-03-03 05:46:23 UTC",
                           "2016-03-03 05:46:29 UTC","2016-03-03 05:46:45 UTC","2016-03-03 05:47:03 UTC","2016-03-03 05:47:19 UTC",
                           "2016-03-03 05:47:37 UTC","2016-03-03 05:47:51 UTC","2016-03-03 05:47:56 UTC","2016-03-03 05:48:03 UTC",
                           "2016-03-03 05:48:04 UTC","2016-03-03 05:48:10 UTC","2016-03-03 05:48:18 UTC","2016-03-03 05:48:27 UTC",
                           "2016-03-03 05:48:45 UTC"),
                Index=c(rep(NA,7),"68362","68364","68364","68364","68352","427292","427292",
                        "427292","427292","255720","255720","255720","255720","255720","255721","255721","255721","255721","255721","255721","255721",
                        "255713"))
```

**df2 looks like:**

```
 df2 <- data.frame(Index=c("68362","68363","68364","68365","68352","68351","68373","68372","68371","427292","255720","255721","255713"))
```

**My code looks like:**

```
library(lubridate)

insertFromDF2 <- function(df_1, df_2) {
  #datetime is in wrong format
  df_1$datetime <- parse_date_time(df_1$datetime, orders="ymd HMS")
  #iteration index will be used to access df_1
  iteration <- 1
  #help var for storing seconds
  last_date <- 1
  temp <- data.frame()
  #list used to store all inserted rows
  l <- list()
  #list index will be used to access l
  l_index <- 1
  newR <- data.frame(datetime=NA,Index=NA)
  #loop through the df_2 and check if row with current Index exists in df_1
  for (i in 1:nrow(df_2)) { 
    #skip NA rows in df1
    while(is.na(df_1$Index[iteration])) {
      iteration <- iteration + 1
    }
    #skip if rows with current Index exist in df_1
    if(df_1$Index[iteration] == df_2$Index[i]) {
      while(df_1$Index[iteration] == df_2$Index[i] & iteration < nrow(df_1)) {
        iteration <- iteration + 1
      }
      last_date <- 1
      next
    }
    
    #I used datetime as a help column for correct order, I used time from the previous row and add 1 second
    newR$datetime <- df_1$datetime[iteration - 1] + lubridate::seconds(last_date)
    #copy columns from df_2 to new row, which will be inserted do df_1
    newR[2] <- df_2$Index[i]
    #increment help var for storing seconds, which will be used in next iteration
    last_date <- last_date + 1
    #store new row in list
    l[[l_index]] <- newR
    l_index <- l_index + 1
  }
  
  #at the end call rbind to combine list with df_1
  temp <- do.call("rbind", l)
  #highlight inserted rows
  temp$inserted <- 1
  df_1$inserted <- 0
  df_1 <- rbind(temp,df_1) 
  #order by datetime
  df_1 <- df_1[order(df_1$datetime),]
  
  return (df_1)   
}

#make some magic
df <- insertFromDF2(df1,df2)
```

Comment: Could you explain the code? Or comment it? I'd love to help you accomplish your goal, but the extra puzzle of "what does this code do" makes it less fun to help...

Comment: Even modifying the example so there's something to distinguish the new rows from the old rows in the result... I run your code and get a bunch of rows with "Anything" in them.

Comment: can you explain what is the desired behavior the same index shows up in df1 and df2 will df1 entry take precedence or .....?

Comment: I added some comments and highlighted inserted rows in result. I just want to combine df1 and df2 and want to keep the correct order of rows, I think if you run the example it is clear.

Comment: Abdessabour Mtk, it's something like a left join. I have the correct sequence of Index columns stored in df2, if the Index is missing in the sequence in df1, I want to insert it in the correct position.

Comment: @jorginho97 I added an answer

Comment: This is too much code to address the question you are asking.  Please try and simplify to a minimally-reproducible example. Even if running all your code makes for a clear example, with so many lines, it's not clear where or how issues may occur.  Additionally, please provide expected output, even if it's just the `head()` version.  Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code but it errors saying tht rbind finds different column names, however I present here an answer:

```r
df2  %>%
 # use this if you want to filter out the indices that are found in df1
 # remove if you want to keep all the rows
 filter(!Index %in% df1$Index) %>%
 # bind the resulting df with df1
  bind_rows(df1, .) %>%
 # convert the columns to their true types
   mutate(datetime= ymd_hms(datetime), Index=as.numeric(Index)) %>%
 # arrange by index and datetime the tibble step is important somehow a simple data.frame forgets the types
    arrange(Index, datetime) %>%
 # add a flag if date is NA
     mutate(nas = is.na(datetime)) %>%
 # fill the dates by the date that was above if value is na
      fill(datetime, .direction="downup") %>% group_by(datetime) %>%
 # add the cumsum of na flag column to the datetime to mimic adding n seconds if date was at first na
      mutate(datetime=datetime + cumsum(nas), nas=NULL) %>% ungroup %>% arrange(datetime)
```

```
# A tibble: 35 x 5
   datetime            Index someColumn1 someColumn2 nas  
   <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>       <chr>       <lgl>
 1 2016-03-02 16:44:32    NA Anything    Anything    FALSE
 2 2016-03-02 16:51:32    NA Anything    Anything    FALSE
 3 2016-03-02 16:53:45    NA Anything    Anything    FALSE
 4 2016-03-02 19:12:15    NA Anything    Anything    FALSE
 5 2016-03-02 19:12:32    NA Anything    Anything    FALSE
 6 2016-03-02 19:12:36    NA Anything    Anything    FALSE
 7 2016-03-02 19:13:50    NA Anything    Anything    FALSE
 8 2016-03-03 05:44:54 68362 Anything    Anything    FALSE
 9 2016-03-03 05:44:55 68363 Anything    Anything    TRUE 
10 2016-03-03 05:45:06 68364 Anything    Anything    FALSE
# … with 25 more rows
```

**Data**

Same data that was provided in the question but with setting the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
df2 <- data.frame(Index=c("68362","68363","68364","68365","68352","68351","68373","68372","68371","427292","255720","255721","255713"),
                someColumn1=rep("Anything",13),
                someColumn2=rep("Anything",13), stringsAsFactors = F)

df1 <- data.frame(datetime=c("2016-03-02 16:44:32 UTC","2016-03-02 16:51:32 UTC","2016-03-02 16:53:45 UTC","2016-03-02 19:12:15 UTC",
            "2016-03-02 19:12:32 UTC","2016-03-02 19:12:36 UTC","2016-03-02 19:13:50 UTC","2016-03-03 05:44:54 UTC",
            "2016-03-03 05:45:06 UTC","2016-03-03 05:45:11 UTC","2016-03-03 05:45:27 UTC","2016-03-03 05:45:42 UTC",
            "2016-03-03 05:45:52 UTC","2016-03-03 05:45:57 UTC","2016-03-03 05:46:12 UTC","2016-03-03 05:46:23 UTC",
            "2016-03-03 05:46:29 UTC","2016-03-03 05:46:45 UTC","2016-03-03 05:47:03 UTC","2016-03-03 05:47:19 UTC",
            "2016-03-03 05:47:37 UTC","2016-03-03 05:47:51 UTC","2016-03-03 05:47:56 UTC","2016-03-03 05:48:03 UTC",
            "2016-03-03 05:48:04 UTC","2016-03-03 05:48:10 UTC","2016-03-03 05:48:18 UTC","2016-03-03 05:48:27 UTC",
            "2016-03-03 05:48:45 UTC"),
    Index=c(rep(NA,7),"68362","68364","68364","68364","68352","427292","427292",
            "427292","427292","255720","255720","255720","255720","255720","255721","255721","255721","255721","255721","255721","255721",
            "255713"),
    someColumn1=rep("Anything",29),
    someColumn2=rep("Anything",29), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this error occurs: "Error in ifelse(is.na(datetime), ymd_hms(lag(df1$datetime)) + 1, datetime) : 
  object 'datetime' not found"

Comment: clearly the data.frame you're using doesn't have the datetime column you provided in your question try running `colnames(df)` and see if there is a datetime entry there

Comment: The error was caused by using tibble, your solution is almost right but the inserted rows do not have correct datetime, e.g. Index 68363 must have '2016-03-03 05:44:55' not '2016-03-02 16:53:46'. But thanks a lot again!

Comment: @jorginho97 true I had used `df1$datetime` instead of `datetime`, I updated the code and now it works as expected

Comment: there are still some mismatch in datetime column, but I have already correct solution!

Comment: i don't see where the mismatch is can u explain further? @jorginho97

Comment: In the result from your code Index 68351 has datetime: NA, but there should be 05:45:43, because Index 68351 is in df2 after 68352(and this Index 68352 has 05:45:42 in df1).

Comment: @jorginho97 this is easily solved by changing the direction param of `fill`, however due to the fact that 68364 in time comes before 68352 that means 68365, 68371, 68372, 68373 will come before 68351, although this is what you described in your first question tbh.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it is based on a solution from @Abdessabour Mtk with some improvements. My code takes into account that Index column is not unique, so it may appear multiple times in df1 and also inserted rows have correct datetime.

```
df2  %>%
    # bind the resulting df with df1
    bind_rows(df1, .) %>%
    # convert the columns to their true types
    mutate(datetime=ymd_hms(datetime), Index=as.numeric(Index)) -> result_df 
    
  # correct Index order
  result_df[order(match(result_df$Index, df2$Index)), ] %>% 
    #filter duplicate Indexes 
    group_by(Index) %>% mutate(drop=ifelse(row_number() > 1 & is.na(datetime),1,0)) %>% 
    filter(drop != 1) %>% ungroup() %>%
    # add a flag if datetime is NA
    group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(datetime))) %>%
    mutate(NAs = ifelse(is.na(datetime), lag(cumsum(is.na(datetime))) + 1, 0)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% select(-grp) %>% 
    # fill the dates by the date that was above if value is na
    fill(datetime, .direction="down") %>%
    # add the na flag column to the datetime to mimic adding a second if date was at first na
    mutate(datetime=datetime + NAs, NAs=NULL, grp=NULL, drop=NULL) -> result_df
  
  #at the end order by datetime 
  result_df <- result_df[order(result_df$datetime),]
```